# Unable to run scripts with arcpy using ArcGIS Pro and Pycharm?

Tags: arcpy, installation, arcgis-pro, pycharm

I have installed ArcGIS Pro 2.0 which runs Python 3.5.3. I am trying to get started with the Arcpy library using the IDE PyCharm.
I started a new project and pointed to the python file of the ArcGIS Pro installation (interpreter):

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe
```

Then I tried to execute the following two lines of code:

```
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/me"
```

And I get an error:

```
 from arcpy import env
 ImportError: cannot import name 'env'
```

I tried as well with different modules from arcpy but they all return the same error; meaning that they can not import each module.

Then I tried to run the same lines of code through the Python Console embedded in PyCharm and it works.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A couple of errors jump out at me here. Note that the line numbers I reference below refer to the line numbers in your screenshot.

Firstly, `arcpy` in line 3 is undefined. Since you called `from arcpy import env`, you should set your workspace by changing `env.workspace`, *not* `arcpy.env.workspace`. If instead line 2 was `import arcpy`, your line 3 would be appropriate.

Second, according to your screenshot, it seems that the file you have created is called `arcpy.py`. What is likely happening is that, upon calling `from arcpy import env`, your script is trying to import `env` from the `arcpy` module. However, because your script's filename is arcpy.py, *it thinks that it is the* `arcpy` *module you are seeking*, and it is trying to import `env` *from itself*, hence the `ImportError`! Renaming your script so that it doesn't conflict with the name of a module you wish to import, such as should solve the problem.

PyCharm has highlighted `arcpy` in line 2 (your first non-blank line). If you hover over the highlight, PyCharm should display something like: *Unused import statement 'from arcpy import env'* and *Import resolves to its containing file*.

Hopefully you solved your problem a couple of years ago, but I post this today with hope that it might help someone in the future!